# How to implement this feature, like in Weather app?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift

I'm interested in how to show/hide UIView when dragging and cling to the borders.
What the method it was implemented, UIKit-UIDynamics?

[image]

Comment: I haven't tried anything. I just want to find right way to implement it. I have one idea about using UIAttachmentBehavior and UICollisionBehavior, but I'm not sure that it's right way.

Answer (score 3):

You need to animate a height constraint of the temperature label (or custom view, I don't know what that is).

So, just link an IBOutlet to the height constraint and animate it

```
func animateCloseWith(float: CGFloat) {
    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.3, animations: { () -> Void in
                self.myConstraint.constant = self.myConstraint.constant - float //for the height
                self.myView.alpha = Float(float) //for the fade effect
            })
}
```

then just call it from the scrollView delegate

```
optional func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    animateCloseWith(scrollView.contentOffset.y)
}
```

Comment: scrollView.contentOffset.y, not x ;)

Answer (score 1):

### First of all:

Consider looking on the web for your solution before asking here on Stack!

---

I was developing an app in the past and found a neat solution for this. If you ask me: This repository looks exactly as the Yahoo-weather app which is about 90 similar to the apple weather app.

It is written in `Obj-C`, therefore I would **suggest** using `Obj-C` to implement it.

You just need to **customize** the views to get the clouds, suns, labels, horizontal `scrollViews` and all the other stuff.

To show/hide a `UIView` you could simply use `scrollView.contentOffset` in the `scrollViewDidScroll` method to show/hide the desired `UILabel`/`UIView`!

Check here: [Get current position of animated scrollview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7346952/get-current-position-of-animated-scrollview)

[BTScrollView](https://github.com/BTLibrary/BTGlassScrollView)

**Download** the project and run the samples to test it! :)

Here you got an additonal screenshot:

[image]

**Cheers!**